# Problemas al cargar datos en una lista

Tags: android

Me encuentro con un problema medio raro , al cargar datos de un JSON en una lista de artículos `codigo`, `descripcion`, `precio` y `ubicacion` dentro de la lista hay articulos que tienen promociones y otros no.

Cuando deseo rellenar la lista con todo los artículos (con o sin promoción) no me rellena el adaptador de la lista, porque el primer artículo no tiene promoción, pero si cargo los artículos sin pedir `promocion` funciona.

Mi código:

```
  protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        prod = new ArrayList<>();
        lista_eligida = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

        String url = "http://danbijann.freeiz.com/tareas.json";
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        JSONObject jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(jsonStr));
            Log.e("JSON", String.valueOf(jsonStr));
            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("PEDIDOS");
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                String codig = c.getString("codigo");
                String des = c.getString("descrip");
                String prec = c.getString("precio");
                String cantidad = c.getString("cantidad");
                String ubica = c.getString("ubica");
                String prueba = c.getString("prueba");
                String promocion = c.getString("promocion");
                String prueba2 = c.getString("prueba2");

                HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();
                contacto.put("codigo", codig);
                contacto.put("descrip", des);
                contacto.put("precio", prec);
                contacto.put("cantidad", cantidad);
                contacto.put("ubica", ubica);
                contacto.put("preuba", prueba);
                contacto.put("promocion", promocion);
                contacto.put("prueba2", prueba2);

                Log.d("ADAP", codig);
                Log.d("ADAP", des);
                Log.d("ADAP", prec);
                Log.d("ADAP", cantidad);
                Log.d("ADAP", ubica);

                prod.add(contacto);
            }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
                e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Prueba.this, prod,
                R.layout.item_carrito, new String[]{ "codigo", "descrip", "precio", "cantidad","ubica","prueba","promocion","prueba2"},
                new int[]{R.id.txtcodigo, R.id.txtdescrip, R.id.txtprecio, R.id.cantidad, R.id.txtubica, R.id.txtprueba, R.id.txtpromo, R.id.txtprueba2});
        lista_eligida.setAdapter(adapter);
                registerForContextMenu(lista_eligida);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al hacer getString() de un campo inexistente la ejecucion falla y es atrapada por el catch entonces todo el resto de codigo dentro del try no ejecuta y el Hasmap nunca se crea.
Siempre que leas campos de un Json asegurate de validar si existen.

Esta forma de validar es la que a mi mas me gusta:

```
String promocion = (json.has("promocion") && !objJson.isNull("promocion"))?
   c.getString("promocion"):"";
```

Sino la vieja y confiable:

```
String promocion = "";
if(objJson.has("promocion") && !objJson.isNull("promocion")) {
   promocion = c.getString("promocion");
}
```

Un consejo, no lo hagas solo con el campo que falle sino con todos los campos que leas del Json para tener un codigo mas robusto.

Comment: Gracias @Erick Silva por su apoyo , pero probe losdos ejemplos me tira los mismos resultado , solo me trae los 5 primeros datos para cada articulos

Comment: Gracias @Erick lo solucione usando tu ejemplo  muchas funciona bien  ahora :)

Answer (score 1):

Es debido a que en tu servicio no envias los datos de la promocion y tu estas queriendo obtener esos datos lo que puedes hacer es hacer uso del metodo .has del Json, algo asi deberia ser.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        prod = new ArrayList<>();
        lista_eligida = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

        String url = "http://danbijann.freeiz.com/tareas.json";
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        JSONObject jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(jsonStr));
            Log.e("JSON", String.valueOf(jsonStr));
            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("PEDIDOS");
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                String codig = c.getString("codigo");
                String des = c.getString("descrip");
                String prec = c.getString("precio");
                String cantidad = c.getString("cantidad");
                String ubica = c.getString("ubica");

                String prueba = "";
                if(objJson.has("prueba") && !objJson.isNull("prueba")){
                    prueba = c.getString("prueba");
                }

                String promocion = "";
                if(objJson.has("promocion") && !objJson.isNull("promocion")) {
                    promocion = c.getString("promocion");
                }

                String prueba2 = "";
                if(objJson.has("prueba2") && !objJson.isNull("prueba2")) {
                    prueba2 = c.getString("prueba2");    
                }


                HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();
                contacto.put("codigo", codig);
                contacto.put("descrip", des);
                contacto.put("precio", prec);
                contacto.put("cantidad", cantidad);
                contacto.put("ubica", ubica);
                contacto.put("preuba", prueba);
                contacto.put("promocion", promocion);
                contacto.put("prueba2", prueba2);

                Log.d("ADAP", codig);
                Log.d("ADAP", des);
                Log.d("ADAP", prec);
                Log.d("ADAP", cantidad);
                Log.d("ADAP", ubica);

                prod.add(contacto);
            }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Prueba.this, prod,
                R.layout.item_carrito, new String[]{ "codigo", "descrip", "precio", "cantidad","ubica","prueba","promocion","prueba2"},
                new int[]{R.id.txtcodigo, R.id.txtdescrip, R.id.txtprecio, R.id.cantidad, R.id.txtubica, R.id.txtprueba, R.id.txtpromo, R.id.txtprueba2});
        lista_eligida.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(lista_eligida);

    }
```

De esa manera verificas si existe el campo y tambien si no esta en nulo

Comment: Gracias @Kenji pero no funciona sigue igual